# HTML5 video is not displayed. Black screen - loading briefly

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

I have an input field where a user can select a video in mp4 format. I then pack this into an array and want to iterate through it and display each video. Unfortunately that doesn't work because I always get a black background in the video. It loads briefly, but then nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
{videos.length > 0 &&
   videos?.map((video, idx) => (
    <div key={idx} className="relative">
        <video muted controls style={{ width: "100%", height: 200 }} autoPlay>
                <source src={video}></source>
        </video>
     ...
    </div> 
 ))}
```

Video is filled:

[image]

But nothing happens:

[image]